# Http requests working in browser/postman, timeout when using curl or python client

Tags: python, curl, postman

We are trying to connect APIs on an internal network using [Pulse Secure VPN](https://www.pulsesecure.net/connect-secure/overview/), requests (POST + GET) via browser(chrome + safari) as well as Postman works perfectly but we receive a timeout when we do the same request using curl or a python client. We have tried explicitly setting the user agent header as well as included all the request headers which the browser includes, setting the tls version, setting the interface. Verbose output just prints `Trying IP ADDRESS HERE...`

Note: There is another API service running on the same network which we are able to connect to via curl.

Any ideas as to what else might be causing this issue

Comment: Proxy issue maybe? Try setting `http_proxy`, `https_proxy`, and `ftp_proxy` variables

Comment: What is the command you use?

Comment: @COLDSPEED the command we use was combinations of `curl` ie `curl --tlsv1.2 URL_HERE`, `curl --tlsv1.2 -A "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_10_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36" URL_HERE` etc.

Comment: @Błażej Michalik We do not set any proxy settings in the browser, or system, we were also not provided any proxy details. But we have tried 'following' hops on the destination network as well

Comment: @devo I'm asking, because from my experience, `curl` and other console utilities tend to disregard system settings (well, not so much disregard as just can't do otherwise). Whatever is set outside of the environment of the utility, it won't see. My other idea would be that it disregards routing to the VPN, and tries to communicate through different interface. You could find that out easily with Wireshark/Netstat.

Comment: @Błażej Michalik we also forced the interface using `--interface` to the tunnel interface listed when you enter `ifconfig` and confirmed that traffic is being routed in the same way as the successful browser requests

Comment: @devo In that case, I would use wireshark on that interface, and create two captures: one when connecting through the browser, and one when connecting through `curl`. See where the differences are, and why.